# R Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! XMLtoList

Tags: r, xml, database, encoding, utf-8

Here is my code, I have a query that I transform in UTF8 but finally I get an error that the query is not in UTF8 I don't manage to fix it:

```
library("XML")
library("methods")
library("httr")

query = http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=(au:( \"Benoit Bertrand\"))&start=0&max_results=2000
xml_data = xmlToList(iconv(URLencode(query),to="UTF-8"))
```

> Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>   Bytes: 0xC9 0x70 0x69 0x6A

I find that's space character that made the code crash but that is all I got

Comment: Post code that actually compiles. What you posted contains `queey` in one line and `querry` in the next. `xmlToList` is called on the URL, not the results of the HTTP request.  `URLencode` is called on a *perfectly valid* URL resulting in double encoding and  `iconv` is called on that string that's already UTF8 -  UTF8 is *indistinguishable* from ANSI in the 0-127 range. You could have written just `r<-GET(query)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's code won't compile due to misspellings. Even if those errors were fixed, the code doesn't do something useful - `xmlToList` is applied on the *URL*, not the results of a GET request. That's enough to generate the error :

```
query<-"http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=(au:( \"Benoit Bertrand\"))&start=0&max_results=2000"
xmlToList(query)
```

No amount of URL encoding and conversions will fix that. No conversion is needed either, since the URL falls in the US-ASCII range. In that range a UTF8 string is indistinguishable from an ASCII string.

The correct code to get and parse this Arxiv page is :

```
//Just a URL
query<-"http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=(au:( \"Benoit Bertrand\"))&start=0&max_results=2000"
//Get the contents
r <- GET(query)
//Extract the text from the response
xml<-content(r, "text")
//Read as lists
l<-xmlToList(xml)
```

The response `r` isn't just a string, it's an object that contains headers (including the encoding), the response status and the response content. One of the headers is the Content-Type :

```
> r
Response [http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=(au:( "Benoit Bertrand"))&start=0&max_results=2000]
  Date: 2019-09-30 12:54
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 786 B
```

`content(r, "text")` converts the content to text using the encoding stored in that header.

After that, `xmlToList` can parse the XML string

Comment: it work for the error but i don't have the result expected but thanks. it's like tj=he reponse is not read properly